# Regex error on Safari. ? The preceding token is not quantifiable

Tags: javascript, regex, highlight

I'm getting the error "? The preceding token is not quantifiable" when executing a Regex in Safari:

```js
const replaceWord = (word, highlightColor) => {
    return `<span style='color: ${highlightColor} !important; font-weight: bold !important;'>${word}</span>`;
};

let message = `masterworld worldwide world business businesses
  <br />
  Gamification_in_the.Business.World.html
  <br />
  Gamification_in_the_Business>World.html
  <br/ >
  Gamification_in_the_Business_World.html
  <br />
  Gamification-in-the-Business-World.html`;

message = message.replace(
    // it was like this before: /* /\bbusiness\b|\bworld\b/gi, */
    // but since it need also to match business_world as two words, I changed to:
    /(?<![^\W_])business(?![^\W_])|(?<![^\W_])world(?![^\W_])/gi,
    (matched, offset, text) => {
        if (matched) {
            return replaceWord(matched, 'red');
        }
        return "";
    }
);

document.write(message);
```

But it's breaking on Safari. I get "? The preceding token is not quantifiable"

https://regex101.com/r/JpmF92/1

Is there an equivalent Regex for me to search word(s) in a text and consider _ (underscore) as a separator?

When searching for "business world" I should get:

```
Business.World = match
Business_World = match
Business-World = match
Business>World = match
Business+World = match
businessworld = NO match
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, in order to fix this, when replacing, you need to use capturing groups that match a reverse context. In the replacement, all you need to add is backreference(s).

See this JavaScript demo:

```js
let message = "masterworld worldwide world business businesses<br />Gamification_in_the.Business.World.html<br />Gamification_in_the_Business>World.html<br/ >Gamification_in_the_Business_World.html<br />Gamification-in-the-Business-World.html";
message = message.replace(
    /([\W_]|^)(business|world)(?![^\W_])/gi,
    "$1<span style='color: red !important; font-weight: bold !important;'>$2</span>"
);
document.body.innerHTML = message;
```

Now, the pattern looks like `([\W_]|^)(business|world)(?![^\W_])`:

- `([\W_]|^)` - Group 1 (`$1`): a non-word char or an underscore or start of string
- `(business|world)` - Group 2: one of the two words
- `(?![^\W_])` - a negative lookahead that checks if the next char is a non-word or `_`.

Now, in the replacement pattern, `$1` refers to the char captured into Group 1 (the boundary char or start of string) and `$2` refers to the word captured into Group 2.

If you want to keep your replacing logic with a callback function, you need to remember that captured values also need to be passed to that function:

```js
const replaceWord = (left, word, highlightColor) => {
    return `${left}<span style='color: ${highlightColor} !important; font-weight: bold !important;'>${word}</span>`;
};

let message = "masterworld worldwide world business businesses<br />Gamification_in_the.Business.World.html<br />Gamification_in_the_Business>World.html<br/ >Gamification_in_the_Business_World.html<br />Gamification-in-the-Business-World.html";

message = message.replace(
    /([\W_]|^)(business|world)(?![^\W_])/gi,
    (matched, group1, group2, offset, text) => {
        return replaceWord(group1, group2, 'red');
    }
);
document.body.innerHTML = message;
```

Note:

- `if (matched)` makes no sense, there is always a match if the code went into the callback function (it is only called when there is a match)
- `(matched, group1, group2, offset, text) => return replaceWord(group1, group2, 'red')` now features group values, and `group1` is the left context and `group2` is your matched `word`.
- `replacedWord` now takes `left` argument, too, and the return value is prefixed with the `left` text.